# Cleaning/formatting URLs

Tags: c#, sharepoint

If I have the following URL:

1. /sites/testsite/subsite/shared%20documents1/projects/project%20-%20csf%20healthcare%20patient%20dining%20development
2. /sites/testsite/subsite2/healthcare/sd/Documents/Cleaning%20Services

I need to be able to clean the URLs so I do this with the following:

```
string webUrl = sd.Key.Substring(0, sd.Key.ToLower().IndexOf("documents") - 1);
```

This works great for the 2 second link and it gives me the following cleaned up URL:

> /sites/testsite/subsite2/healthcare/sd

This however is not universal and it does not work for the first Url, and what I get is the following:

> /sites/testsite/subsite/Shared%2

Ideally what I would want to get here is

> /sites/testsite/subsite

Is there a better way (universal) to ensure that this works for both URLs?

Comment: Personally, I would first URL-decode the strings before doing anything else.

Comment: I'm thinking a regex that involves `\/(shared%20)?documents\/`...

Answer (score 1):

These are escaped strings, use javascript function unescape() to unescape them.

e.g.

```
unescape('/sites/testsite/subsite/shared%20documents1/projects/project%20-%20csf%20healthcare%20patient%20dining%20development')

//sites/testsite/subsite/shared documents1/projects/project - csf healthcare patient dining development
```

And use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in C#

```
var result = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("/sites/testsite/subsite/shared%20documents1/projects/project%20-%20csf%20healthcare%20patient%20dining%20development");
```

Comment: not sure that this is relevant to the question, frankly

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using `Uri.UnescapeDataString`

```
 Uri.UnescapeDataString(@"/sites/testsite/subsite/shared%20documents1/projects/project%20-%20csf%20healthcare%20patient%20dining%20development")
```

this will give you

```
/sites/testsite/subsite/shared documents1/projects/project - csf healthcare patient dining development
```

then you can remove spaces if you want to. for more information use this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve just "/sites/sitename/subsite" you can do this

```
var match = Regex.Match("/sites/compass/community/Shared%20documents1/projects/project%20-%20csf%20healthcare%20patient%20dining%20development", "^/sites/.*?/.*?/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value) // "/sites/compass/community"
```

Or in order to retrieve everything left from /*documents

```
var source = new [] {"/sites/testsite/subsite/shared%20documents1/projects/project%20-%20csf%20healthcare%20patient%20dining%20development", 
        "/sites/testsite/subsite2/healthcare/sd/Documents/Cleaning%20Services"};

foreach (var item in source)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(item, "^(.*)(?:/.*?Documents)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
/sites/testsite/subsite
/sites/testsite/subsite2/healthcare/sd
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have updated the URLs above so that the question makes more sense. Essentially the "Documets" and "Shared%20Documents" and eveything after that needs to be stripped off URL so that the URLs end up as "/sites/testsite/subsite2/healthcare/sd" and "/sites/testsite/subsite". What I have at the moment does this well for the second URL by using IndexOf("documents" -1) but this does not work well for the first URL since it contains "shared%20documents1" if that makes sense